# Unable to query PermissionSetAssignment object

Tags: apex, profile, permission-sets, security-review, sobjecttype

I have a method in my package's postInstall script that is trying to check to see if the user has access to edit custom settings. In the method, I query the `PermissionSetAssignment` object. When I run the method from the Developer Console, everything works, but when it is run as part of the postInstall, it fails with the following error: `sObject type 'PermissionSetAssignment' is not supported.`

The query I'm using is:

```
[SELECT Id, PermissionSet.PermissionsCustomizeApplication FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId =: UserInfo.getUserId()]
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I am running the method as a System Administrator.

Comment: Is that package's postinstall script running as system admin user?

Comment: The package is installed by the System Admin user, so I would assume the post install script runs as System Administrator.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that this package does not have API access restricted?

Comment: Is there a specific permission related to that? I checked the packaging org, and the package has the `API Enabled` permission checked.

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this?